# Book recommendations: Deepen statistical understanding

Tags: anova, t-test, references, ancova, manova

I'm a psychology undergraduate and I would like to deepen my understanding of statistics beyond what is required for my studies. I'm looking for book suggestions dealing with Anova, Ancova, T-tests etc in a mathematical way. My goal is to understand the underlying concepts of the tests we use and the reasoning behind them. I have a German high school education in mathematics, but a genuine interest for the topic.

Comment: Applied Linear Statistical Models by Kutner Nachtsheim Neter and Li is a good text dealing with statistical testing alone. The mathematics of T-test, ANCOVA, and so on are really very simple: no more than algebra. The challenge in undergraduate coursework is interpreting estimators, standard errors, confidence intervals, and p-values correctly. There are texts dealing with statistics (and probability) at a calculus/measure theory level but these would not enhance your psychology education, or (more precisely) would not improve your expected mastery of statistics at this stage.

Comment: Another possibility is "All of Statistic" by Wasserman.  It was designed around a stat class for people interested in ML.

Comment: Without some understanding of what level of understanding you have this questions isn't answerable. And even then it's probably too broad.

Comment: If you are studying psychology in a German university (are you?), then you should have had a number of statistics courses. Your best bet would be to approach your statistics instructor and ask for further reading.

Comment: I thank you for your suggestions and thoughts on this matter. I know this question is rather broad, but I think AdamO and Aginesky made suggestions I can and will definitely work with. @StephanKolassa: True, I could and probably should also do that.